# Back reference attribute error in SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following classes:

```
from app import db

class TransactionStatus(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction_status'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='transaction_status', lazy='dynamic')

class Transaction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    transaction_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('transaction_status.id'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.transaction_status_id} {self.transaction_status}'
```

but I'm getting the following error when I try to access the `transaction_status`:

```
AttributeError: 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'transaction_status'
```

However the `transaction_status_id` attribute does exist, so I'm not sure why the backref is not working in this instance. I though it was because of the underscores, so I specified the `__tablename__` attribute but this doesn't help.

How can I get this to work, please? Thanks in advance for any help here! :-)

Comment: Something seems wonky to me but I'm struggling to pin it down, sorry. It seems to me that the relationship should be in your `Transactions` class

Comment: `TransactionStatus` looks like it's a defined set of stages a transaction can be in. But that's a finite set of states. `Transaction` is unbound; you'll keep getting more transactions as time goes on. I still think the `relationship` needs to be defined in the `Transaction` class

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for your input.... Indeed it seems maybe that the name causes this issue (i.e. contains "transaction") as you have to put it in quotes when reading in SQLite. Strange though! Might just have to rename the classes ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to in relation to SQLite on its own, but it's almost certainly an incorrect conclusion if you're trying to diagnose a problem with the ORM

Comment: SQLite3 does have issues in data types (in that it doesn't actually strictly enforce them) but that can't be the cause of an `AttributeError` from the ORM

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah you're probably right, but I also have  `service_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('service.id'))`  and the `Service` class has `transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='service', lazy='dynamic')` so I thought it'd work .... could it be the underscore in `transaction_status`?

Comment: From what I can see, your `Transaction` object has an attribute named `transaction_status_id` but does not have one named `transaction_status`.